# Why bind OpenGL buffer objects?

Tags: opengl, 3d, kotlin, lwjgl

In OpenGL a general procedure is to bind a named buffer object (or vertex array object, framebuffer, ...), invoke some operations on the currently bound object and then bind some kind of "default" object:

```
glBindBufferObject(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObjectName)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBufferObject(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
```

(LWJGL in Kotlin)

I just discovered that there are "named" version for many functions. The example from above would become something like

```
glNamedBufferData(bufferObjectName, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

which is way more suitable in an object-oriented context.

So why use something like in the first example? Every tutorial I came upon used the first approach, so is there some performance lost or similar downsides in the "named" approach?

Comment: The "named" functions are only available in newer versions of OpenGL such as 4.5. They did not exist before. What to use depends on whether you want to ensure compatibility with older hardware or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The named functions are part of the `ARB_direct_state_access` extension which was introduced in OpenGL 4.5. Before that only the normal methods existed.

The main reason for using the older version is when targeting pre OpenGL 4.5 hardware. Most tutorials are also written against older versions of OpenGL.

Comment: @Hitokage: What exactly do you mean? It is core since 4.5.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake.